# How to use non-Metro app Chrome as my default browser?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, modern-ui

Setting Google Chrome in my default programs always leads to using the Google Chrome Metro app.

How can I use the desktop one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit the registry. You can find detailed steps with screenshots here:
http://meta.superuser.com/a/5816/121933